# Difference between single inverted comma and apostrophe?

Tags: c, apostrophe

Example `char fi= 'a';`.
What do we call it here: apostrophe or single inverted comma?

Comment: I doubt it can be considered a programming question though

Comment: apostrophes are used _singular_, quotes in _pairs_.  That is a typographical question, not a programming one.  If it were a programming question, they would be _literal character delimiters_ - denoting their syntactic function rather then their typographical name.

Comment: Note that word processors will try to generate "proper" 66/99 distinct quote and apostrophe symbols if you try to use them to write code. Most compilers will not like these symbols. So don't do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about programming. This is more of an English question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code it’s called a **single quote** (C 2018 6.4.4.4 3) to contrast it with *double quotes* (`"`).

“Apostrophe” and “inverted comma” are typographical terms commonly used in regard to English text. Neither is used in a programming context.

Answer (score 1):

> What do we call it here: apostrophe or single inverted comma?

Neither.

It's called **single quotation mark**.

[src](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark)